# How to get a unique identifier using codename one code

Tags: codenameone

I am new to Codename One and would like to know how could i get a unique identifier for the user's phone or an alternative like its Device Mac address.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I Have used Socket.getHostOrIP() to get IP address but it returns me as "localhost" when I check in device with Wifi/2G connection. How could I get the number like 192.168.10.233.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get udid of device which is very unique

https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#getUdid--

```
String uniqueId =Display.getInstance().getUdid()
```

Comment: Notice that UDID is partially fake on iOS and will be different for two separate installations. It also adds a special permission flag on Android.

Comment: iOS specifically banned UDID, we return a meta-udid which should be unique but uninstalling/reinstalling will produce different UDIDs. Apple has an advertiser ID but if you use that you have to explicitly sign with Apple that you are using it only for ads and under specific stipulations. Most apps (e.g. whatsapp) use phone numbers, emails, login as a way to uniquely identify users.

Comment: yes its return null in emulator 
and in device it provides data.

Comment: This code is works for on devices and apple IPAD even on multiple installation I will get unique code for device. Thank You.

Comment: using getUdid() will trigger the "make and manage phone calls" permission, which may alarm your users.